# Search all php files for a string in between a class

Tags: php, regex, class

I am using a simple php translation class and I have about more than 2000 php files which the translation class was implemented and new strings are as well implemented so I need an updated text file with all the translation strings.

I need to get all the translated values from each php file and save it into a text file without any repeated value.

Translation class

```
<?php $translate->__('Calendar'); ?>
```

So I need to get **Calendar** saved into a txt file and this should be done for all the files in all folders.

Everything in between **$translate->__('** and **')** should be saved.

The below code not working for some reason.

```
$fn = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/apps/test/test2/calendar.php";
$handle = fopen($fn, 'r');
$valid = false;
$search = "\/\\$translate\\-\\>__\\(\\'(.*?)'\\)\/g";
while (($buffer = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    if(preg_match_all($search, $buffer, $m)) {
        print $m[1];
    } else {

    }
}
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: Well then, best of luck ! Seriously, please post your attempts so far. StackOverflow is becoming more and more a To-Do list rather than anything else...

Comment: I put my codes already @Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're extracting strings with this pattern:

```
/\$translate\-\>__\(\'(.*?)'\)/g
```

extract all of `match`ed items and save them any where.

Demo and Details : https://regex101.com/r/LzMyJY/1

```
$fn = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/apps/test/test2/calendar.php";
$handle = fopen($fn, 'r');
$valid = false;
$search = "/\\".'$'."translate\\-\\>__\\(\\'(.*?)'\\)/g";

while (($buffer = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    if(preg_match_all($search, $buffer, $m)) {
        print $m[1];
    } else {

    }
}
fclose($handle);
```

**Note**:

- In use of regex patterns, remember handle backslash `\` when putting pattern in `".."` (change all `\` to `\\` in this case)
- If using `'...'` don't change `\` with `\\` !

Comment: I tried your regex however it is not returned any text, you can check the edited codes above. @MohaMad

Comment: you missed backslash ! try this one: `$search = "\/\\$translate\\-\\>__\\(\\'(.*?)'\\)\/g";`

Comment: I get 2 errors: **Notice: Undefined variable: translate in** and **Warning: preg_match_all(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash** @MohaMad

Comment: You should use this one: `$search = "\/\\" . '$' . "translate\\-\\>__\\(\\'(.*?)'\\)\/g"; ` @adams

Comment: Still getting this error: **Warning: preg_match_all(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash** @MohaMad

Comment: Finally: `$search = "/\\".'$'."translate\\-\\>__\\(\\'(.*?)'\\)/g" ; `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136970/discussion-between-mohamad-and-adams).